# getting a seg fault error for some reason when trying to use getopt/optind?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, getopt

When running this program I seem to get a seg fault core dumped error. As far as I know a seg fault is caused by trying to access something out of bounds so I am not sure why this is happening.
After testing various spots with cout I feel like the if statement with optind variable is responsible though I am not sure why. I intended for it to check if the next arg is an not an option (aka an input) then execute something.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cstring>

using namespace std;

class dirls 
{
    public:
        dirls();
        dirls(bool a, bool d, bool f, bool l, bool h);
        void print_usage(string s);
        void longlisting(string dir, vector<string>& files);
        void getdir(string dir, vector<string>& files, bool recursive);
        void initiate(string s, vector<string>& files, vector<string>& paths);
        bool ishflag() { return fflag; };
        
    private:
        bool aflag;
        bool dflag;
        bool fflag;
        bool lflag;
        bool hflag;
       
};
dirls::dirls()
{
    
    aflag = false;
    dflag = false;
    fflag = false;
    lflag = false;
    hflag = false;
}

dirls::dirls(bool a, bool d, bool f, bool l, bool h) 
{
    
    aflag = a;
    dflag = d;
    fflag = f;
    lflag = l;
    hflag = h;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int opt = 0;
    string first = argv[0];
    string dir = argv[1];
    bool a = false, d = false, f = false, l = false, h = false;

    vector<string> files = vector<string>(); // holds the files in a directory
    vector<string> paths = vector<string>(); // holds the paths
    vector<dirls> options = vector<dirls>(); // holds multiple objects and their option flags


    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "adflh")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'a':
            a = true;
            break;
        case 'd':
            d = true;
            break;
        case 'f':
            f = true;
            break;
        case 'l':
            l = true;
            break;
        case 'h':
            h = true;
            break;
        case '?':                           /* error - unknown option */
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (argv[optind][0] != '-') // ISSUE?
            options.push_back(dirls(a, d, f, l, h));
    }

    if (options.empty())
        options.push_back(dirls(a, d, f, l, h));

    

   

    for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
    {
        paths.push_back(argv[i]);
    }

    while (paths.size() < options.size())
    {
        paths.push_back(".");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < paths.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "paths are: " << paths[i] << " "; 
    }
    
    return 0; 

}
```

Comment: Where is `optind` defined? What value does it have? What changes its value? It isn't shown in your code.

Comment: You've been asking questions on this site for a year; has no one told you about [minimal complete examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Try simplifying that code, removing features and mechanisms, and see when the error disappears; show us the simplest example you can find of code that ought to work but doesn't.

Comment: @Beta  ive already reduced it quite a bit (all the functions for the options) but I'll go thought it again.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm optind is defined as 1 by default. I believe it is a global variable

Comment: And what input are you giving it?

Comment: @ Beta on the commandline ./a.out -l  . No input is directly given for optind. I believe its value is modified based on what the function getopt() returns. Its supposed to be the index of the next value in the argv[] vector and is initialized to 1.

Comment: In this case there is no next value, `optind` is the index of the element just past the end of `argv`, and you are trying to read that element. You can check `argc` to prevent this error.

Comment: `optind` is the `getopt` variable holding the index of the next element to be processed in argv.

Comment: @beta so do you thin something like if (argv[optind][0] != '-' && optind < argc)  would work?

Comment: No, since the left argument of `&&` is evaluated before the right. I think `if (optind < argc && argv[optind][0] != '-')` would work, but I'd *test that thoroughly before integrating it with other code.*

Answer (score 1):

Your code accesses invalid memory on the line of `if (argv[optind][0] != '-') // ISSUE?`

If you use a debugger such as `gdb` you can see, after you run it with `a.out -l`, the value of optind == 2, which is not valid.

Comment: Yeah that line was what I thought as well. Any ideas on how to fix the issue? I am trying to check if the next arg is an option flag or not.

Comment: try to use optind - 1 instead of optind

Comment: optind -1 wouldn't that just result in checking the current argument instead of the next?

Comment: I think that is what you want, the current, not the next.